# Memory Leak in Creating Bitmap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, bitmap

I was struggling with memory leak in MVC application for couple of months. I checked every new Bitmap (because we use lots of bitmap in the project)
I found out that nothing is related to the code I developed and realized that every time I create a bitmap and dispose it still there are some bytes is remaining in the memory. I thought maybe some settings, or something else is eating the memory. so I created a fresh MVC aplication and added this method into the homecontroller:

```
 public JsonResult BuildImageFromHDD()
 {

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            using (var myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\temp\test\myJpg2.jpg"))
            {

            }               
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = "done   " + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

    }
```

this action just creates 200 bitmap. As I put the variable inside the using block, I was expecting to see the memory allocated for this app be the same after and before the action is hit. if I hit the action 20 times the memory allocated for my application pool grows from 170 MG to 210 MG and if I continue to hit that method the memory increase and increase steadily 
I thought the GC has not yet collected some garbage. I even called GC.Collect(); at the end of method but no difference.

Now consider that we have 2 million requests every 10 hours and if every 20 * 200 request is supposed to add 40 MG to the memory, every 10 hour I have around 10 Gig memory leak.

I monitor the memory allocation for the application poll in the IIS.

And the application has been built in Release mode.

Comment: Just because memory is allocated to the app pool, doesn't mean it's actually *consuming* that memory. Some amount of memory is often held onto, which might later be released during a GC cycle or simply when the OS requests memory back. This is all part of normal Windows memory optimization.

Comment: But When I keep the application running the allocated memory is increased. I tested it for 30 minutes maybe I have to keep it running for couple of hours ?

Comment: Again, that doesn't mean anything necessarily. When there's available RAM, applications tend to hold onto more than they're actively using. This is because there's some resource cost in allocating memory in the first place, and if there's no other application needing the memory, it doesn't make sense to release it, only to request it back later. There's also various runtime-level caching that goes on under the hood that will utilize RAM, but not lock it, i.e. if the system needs the memory, it will release.

Comment: Long and short, we're past the days of 1 to 1 memory usage. When memory used to be constrained, an application would consume only what it needed and when it was done, it would release every bit of it. Memory is much less limited on systems now, so operating systems employ clever optimization practices to boost the speed of modern systems. You can't really release memory and watch it go like you could before. It all depends on what else is going on in the system.